# Creating a conditional column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have a dataset with 3 columns. Table name is #test. I want to create the 4th column ("Result") that satisfies some conditions. The terms are as follows:

- Get if the first Resolved value of a contact is 0.
- Get if the first value after 1 in the Resolved column is 0. If they continue as 0, do not include them.
- These conditions must be applied separately for each contact.

I am sharing the example below.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help :

```
DECLARE @TMP table (
    ContactCode int,
    HistoryDate date,
    Resolved bit
)

INSERT INTO  @TMP VALUES
(466, '2022-02-28',0),
(466, '2022-03-31',1),
(466, '2022-04-30',0),
(466, '2022-05-31',0),
(466, '2022-06-30',1),
(466, '2022-07-31',0),
(467, '2022-02-28',0),
(467, '2022-03-31',0),
(467, '2022-04-30',0),
(467, '2022-05-31',0),
(467, '2022-06-30',1),
(467, '2022-07-31',0)

SELECT
    ContactCode,
    HistoryDate,
    Resolved,
    CASE
        WHEN
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ContactCode ORDER BY HistoryDate ASC) = 1
            OR LAG(Resolved, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY ContactCode ORDER BY HistoryDate ASC) = 1
            THEN 0
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Result
FROM @TMP
```

Result :

| ContactCode | HistoryDate | Resolved | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 466 | 2022-02-28 | 0 | 0 |
| 466 | 2022-03-31 | 1 | NULL |
| 466 | 2022-04-30 | 0 | 0 |
| 466 | 2022-05-31 | 0 | NULL |
| 466 | 2022-06-30 | 1 | NULL |
| 466 | 2022-07-31 | 0 | 0 |
| 467 | 2022-02-28 | 0 | 0 |
| 467 | 2022-03-31 | 0 | NULL |
| 467 | 2022-04-30 | 0 | NULL |
| 467 | 2022-05-31 | 0 | NULL |
| 467 | 2022-06-30 | 1 | NULL |
| 467 | 2022-07-31 | 0 | 0 |

`ROW_NUMBER()` allows you to 'order' your data in a partition (here your partition is your ContactCode and order by HistoryDate). You then want the first one (`ROW_NUMBER() ... = 1`).

`LAG()` will look for the previous value of `Resolved`, if it's a 1 you print `0`for your current row.

Comment: A good answer provides an explanation in addition to working code.

Comment: The script you sent is working. Thank you!

Comment: @Ogi123 please consider setting the post to 'resolved' by setting the answer to 'solution'